Multiprocessing for CPU-bound task (ML inference) in Jupyter Notebook
I'm working on Windows, on a Jupyter Notebook in VSCode.
I have a list of sentences and I want to apply a Hugging Face model to each one. Each one takes like 1 second, so I figured I could accelerate the process by taking advantage of my 16 CPUs.
For now, the closest I've got to accelerating it is with joblib.
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
import time

from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

# Input

sentences = [
    'The car is awful',
    'The party was amazing',
    'The dish is dirty',
    'My brother is the best',
    'My mom is the worst',
    'This example sucks',
    'The restaurant was so good',
    'I love the landscape',
    'Nature is wonderful',
    'John is terrible'
]

sentences = [x for y in [sentences] * 10 for x in y]

checkpoint = "kevinscaria/joint_tk-instruct-base-def-pos-neg-neut-combined"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

def absa(text):

    prompt = f"""Definition: The output will be the aspects (both implicit and explicit) and the aspects sentiment polarity.
Positive example 1-
input: I charge it at night and skip taking the cord with me because of the good battery life.
output: battery life:positive, 
Negative example 1-
input: Speaking of the browser, it too has problems.
output: browser:negative
Neutral example 1-
input: I took it back for an Asus and same thing- blue screen which required me to remove the battery to reset.
output: battery:neutral
Now complete the following example-
input: {text}\noutput: """
    tokenized_text = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True)
    output = model.generate(tokenized_text.input_ids, max_new_tokens=1000)
    detokenized = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    return detokenized

List comprehension:
%%time
[absa(x) for x in sentences]

# Wall time: 46.2 s

Joblib:
%%time
Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='threading')(delayed(absa)(row) for row in tqdm(sentences))

# Wall time: 29 s

However this only cuts the inference time by 1.6 so it's not really a big improvement. I would expect the inference time to be 1/16 of the time using list comprehension plus some minor overhead.
EDIT:
I've also tried, comparing a dummy function with time.sleep() and mine:

concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor: the dummy function is sped up by x12, mine only by x1.4.
concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor: both functions get a BrokenProcessPool error
ray: the dummy function is sped up by x11, mine gets a value error:
ValueError: The remote function __main__.new_absa is too large (945 MiB > FUNCTION_SIZE_ERROR_THRESHOLD=95 MiB). Check that its definition is not implicitly capturing a large array or other object in scope. Tip: use ray.put() to put large objects in the Ray object store.
joblib: dummy sped up by x12, mine by 1.5
multiprocess: keeps hanging for both

If you want more details I can share the code of one of these options.

When you say "The rest of the strategies I've tried (concurrent.futures, multiprocess) haven't really worked." what do you mean?

I've updated the question with the alternatives I've tried. I can provide the chunks of code if needed.

There is no sped up with threads, because Python <3.13 speed is limited by GIL. This will be solved in few years, stay patient. So your path to speed up is to fix your code so that multiprocessing based concurrency works.

My suggestion is that you open a new joblib question that is specific to the error what happens with multiprocessing and joblib. There is probably something wrong how you pass in data to multiprocessing - essentially you cannot pass large objects directly, because they would be copied between processes and your computer would run out of memory.

Most machine learning apis already use all threads, you don't need to add another layer of parallelism
